# Parse.com version control and deployment

Tags: cloud, parse-platform

I decided to use the Parse.com BaaS as it looked promising. Me and my friend started working on the app and suddenly realized that parse is not giving any option to checkout already existing cloud code. Also if we create new apps on our separate systems the code is completely overridden if one of us tries to deploy the code. Is there something that I am missing ? I would really like to know if we can somehow use version control with Parse.

Comment: have you found a solution yet? we are also suffering from the exact same problem.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu according to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581672/how-can-i-pull-the-latest-cloud-code it is not possible and you should use GitHub if you need source control

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) as version control which you can install in your own server or register  on [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)

Also you can automat deploying to parse using [commit-hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which you can automatically deploy your local copy to parse with each commit

Answer (score 3):

Unfortuntely you cannot use parse.com as a version control software. I would recommend using GitHub. Parse.com is better used as a cloud database management system.

Comment: Yes, we are using it for cloud database and backend functionality, but as we are collaborative, we need a version control system for it.

Comment: Ok, I see what you are saying. Parse doesn't offer any type of version control inherently. Their reasoning behind this is that their databases will never be offline therefore they do not need to offer backups.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu What specifically do you need the Version Control for?

Comment: For all the Javascript files, and syncing our web root, as we can't grab the latest version from the cloud

Comment: Have you looked into GitHub?
Also as an alternative, parse offers the ability to save files. You can maybe save files that way. I wouldn't recommend that tho.

Comment: Well if we can't find anything else, we'll of course end up using git (which I actually hate). I was looking for more of a built-in solution (or a best practice) for Parse itself.