# How can I pull the latest Cloud Code?

Tags: parse-platform

I need to use the command line tool provided by Parse.com to get the latest Cloud Code from my application, how can I do that? I'm working with a team and can not overwrite the existing Cloud Code.

Comment: Not sure.. but, it's not possible.  You should use GitHub or some other version control system.

Comment: It seems some over-zealous moderators didn't understand that this is a valid question in regards to Parse, unfortunately as @Fosco stated it isn't possible... hopefully the question can be reopened so that can be posted as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @TimothyWalters: Both the question and this "answer" are incredibly brief. This post isn't going to help anyone else without further details.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I disagree. There is not much more to mention other then what the user tried (hint!). I am experiencing the same issue and found Fosco's comment very useful, it should be an answer.

Comment: @PaulPeelen: Okay then. It's really on the edge, though; you must see that.

Comment: I disagree that the question is ambiguous. I have the same problem. I was delivered via Git a set of code that I _assume_ is the same as is what's in production, but I need to know **for sure** if they are the same before I start pushing to Production. Is there a way to pull down from Parse Cloud Code the current set of production code (a la old-school FTP download), so that I can do a wholesale diff on both batches? This is literally day one on Parse for me, and I'm under an insane deadline with no other assistance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait... so @TimothyWalters -- are you saying that Fosco's answer is correct and basically the Parse system is "deploy-only"? Seems odd, but I'm willing to accept that... please confirm. Thanks!

Comment: @InteractiveLogic yes, correct. Fosco works at Parse. Although the Dashboard does now have a "Cloud Code" section that lets you browse what has been uploaded to the "cloud" folder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @TimothyWalters. Much appreciated. I've seen the dashboard that lets one browse the code, and that may be what I'll have to use. So, generally speaking is the wholesale deploy of everything the accepted mode of development, or can we also just deploy one .ejs file?

Comment: Everything gets overwritten when you deploy

Comment: OK thanks, @TimothyWalters - that's what I thought was the case. Much appreciated clarification.

Comment: This question should be reopened. It is clear and concise, and is a common issue for Parse.com Cloud Code developers.

Comment: #RepopenMyQuestion2k15

Answer (score 6):

You can now download deployed Cloud Code through the CLI.

Through the command prompt (on Windows) type:

```
parse new
```

Parse will then ask you to provide your user credentials. Once provided, the command prompt will ask, **Would you like to create a new app, or add Cloud Code to an existing app?** Choose **(e)xisting**, and you will be provided with a list of apps you currently have access to to choose from and the rest is cake.

Make sure you update the Parse CLI in order to get this work by using:

```
parse update
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use **parse download** command:

`parse download -l [location]`

Works great in our team. For more information about the command use
`parse download --help`.

Note: if no location is provided, code will be downloaded to a temporary folder.

Comment: This only works if you have already created the project.  Parse new -> (e)xisting is the best (only?) way to start from scratch.

Comment: You should use parse new -> (e)xisting only on the initial creation of the local repository which is reasonable. Parse download is easier. That doesn't matter either way because parse is closing :(

Comment: I can download but it is not show parse version file. .parse.local and .parse.project So I need to copy from old one, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE: You can now download your deployed code easily with the Parse CLI:**

```
parse download
```

**HISTORIAL: Previously (May 11, 2015) there are only 2 ways to get cloud code deployed by someone else on your team:**

1. You get a copy directly from your teammate
2. You go to the Parse.com Core dashboard, tap on Cloud Code (below the Data section with all the classes), then click on each file on at a time and copy/paste the window contents into a file with the appropriate name.

Neither of these are ideal solutions.

**Ideally, your team would use a two-part solution like this:**

1. A version control system (like [Github](http://github.com) or similar) that keeps track of your most recent version
2. A dev mirror of your Parse.com app that gives you a sandbox for testing changes to the code